# How to pas parameters to model in sapui5

Tags: odata, sapui5

I've configured my destination in menifest.js and now I can access my model in controller. Menifestjs file is as

```
    "dataSources": {
        "dlContent": {
            "uri": "/destinations/dles/DL/services/DL_CONTENT.xsodata",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "odataVersion": "2.0"
            }
        }
    },
```

and model

```
    "dlScore": {
            "dataSource": "dlContent"
        }
```

I want to set parameters like filter, and others. 
I'm accessing my model as

```
var mod = this.getView().getModel("dlesScore")
```

this give me link till my `/destinations/dl/DL/services/MY_CONTENT.xsodata/`
I want to access `/destinations/dl/DL/services/MY_CONTENT.xsodata/DLES_CONTENT?$top=1`
how i can add `/DLES_CONTENT?$top=1` in my model to get data.

Comment: which kind of model do you use?

Comment: odataModel, even  JSON model is also okay. https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/44062441f3bd4c67a4f665ae362d1109.html I used this tutorial but now how to get the detail

Comment: you should use OData model and utilize the "read" method.

Comment: I'm not aware of the details . can you give me some link, or just for above data how I will do it ?

Comment: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#read

Comment: It gives me the read property is undefined. I've set my odatamodel in menifestjs fileo mod.read("/dl_Content", {
   
   success: function(oData) {
   console.log(oData);
   }
});

Comment: You need to pass the name of your entity set "/DLES_CONTENT"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can direclty set your model after setting menifestjs file.

```
<List items="{
  path: 'dlesScore>/DLES_CONTENT'
}">
  <ObjectListItem title="{dlesScore>id}" />
</List>
```

[Load OData Service using expand, filter, and sorter](https://embed.plnkr.co/wAlrHB/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use length property in binding for triggering $top query to OData service.
sample code

```
items:{path:"dlesScore>/DLES_CONTENT",length:1,
                template:templateName
            }
```

see sample code with json model [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/roreloquka/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: I wil set this property in menifest.js file?

Comment: I need some more details , can you give me reference link?